# How to check div display property in selenium WDS Jmeter

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, jmeter, webdriver

Hi SatckOverflow Community,

I m newbie for Jmeter and related Stuff.
I need a help.
when i am searching something during waiting time ,a div appears that restrict me to click on other elements..as

`<div id="wait" width="100%" height="100%" class="wait" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left:0px; height: 617px; width: 355px; display: block; cursor: default;"></div>`

when search completes, it turns into
 `<div id="wait" width="100%" height="100%" class="wait" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left:0px; height: 617px; width: 355px; display: none; cursor: default;"></div>`
basically its display change from 'block' to 'none'

As my application requirement i need to wait until 'wait'div display status changes to none..
only after that i should interact with other elements.

how can i chk this in WDS javascript
i tried
wait.until(conditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath(".//*[@id='wait'and not(@style.display)]")));

but i feel its not working .

Any help in this direction will be helpful.Thnks

Comment: Please share what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for visibility of element.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//."));
```

Comment: @Ankur-- i m not getting an error but with result i can see definitely its not waiting for presence of div with display=none rather than block

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting for element's visibility and provide a flaky XPath selector I would rather recommend waiting for element's [invisibility](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-):

```
wait.until(conditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.id("wait")));
```

In addition:

1. Wherever it is possible locate elements by their [IDs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ById.html) as it's the fastest and the most reliable way
2. If you go for [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) - avoid wildcard queries, i.e. replace `.//*[` with `//div` so search would be limited to `div`.
3. In case of any unexpected behaviour check out [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging)  - in case of script malfunction the failure cause will most probably be printed there
4. Check out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) article for more information on WebDriver Sampler's tips and tricks

Comment: @ Dmriti,Thanks for your reaponse ,,But in my case div wait is alz there just its property displaychanges from block  to none and  vice versa....